# Ubuntu 20.04 graphics lag

Tags: nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04, prev version was 19.04, and since the first login I noticed that the gui is a bit laggy, but I didn't care much.
Today I opend Minecraft to play but the framerate was the worst I ever experienced. I was in the nether with no structures around and previously I rarely had any issues there (alway at least 40fps). I checks if it was caused by the raspeberry server or the connection, but no strange logs from the server and for the connection I check in a single player word here the fps was 13 too. If I open youtube the fan go creazy, it wasn't like this with 19.04.
My graphic card is Nvidia quadro K620M, and the current driver is the latest NVIDIA 440 from ubuntu-drivers, so it's must be correct and from the settings it's saying that it's already using NVIDIA.
Somedoby had similar issues?
What can I do?